# CentOS7（kusanagi）にPleskをインストールしたい

Tags: php

Plesk12.5をインストール中にエラーが出てしまいます。

> Exception: Failed to solve dependencies:
>   php-imap-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64 requires php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
>   php-imap-5.4.16-7.el7.x86_64 requires php(api) = 20100412-64

ERROR: The Yum utility failed to install the required packages.

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 update -y
```

など試したのですが変わらずです。

Comment: 詳しくないのですが、http://stackoverflow.com/q/40594662/6366398 参考になりますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。参考にはなると思うのですが、まだ解決には至ってません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plesk のインストールに失敗しているわけですから、その手順をまず記載してはどうでしょうか。

KUSANAGI では通常 remi-php56 などは有効になっていないので、[インストーラー](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213415669-How-to-Install-Plesk-for-Linux)を使ったインストールであれば有効にしてやる必要があります。
yum-utils パッケージに含まれる yum-config-manager コマンドを利用して remi および remi-php56 リポジトリを有効にしてみてください。

```
yum install yum-utils
yum-config-manager --enable remi remi-php56
```